# Оптимизация циклов через развертывание циклов

Tags: c#, .net, производительность

В общем, читал статью на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/467663/), которая является переводом блога майков.

В статье описываются фичи SIMD и приводятся примеры оптимизаций без использование этой фичи.

Тривиальный цикл

```
public int Sum(ReadOnlySpan<int> source)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        result += source[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Цикл, который быстрее предыдущего на 20%:

```
public unsafe int SumUnrolled(ReadOnlySpan<int> source)
{
    int result = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int lastBlockIndex = source.Length - (source.Length % 4);

    // Pin source so we can elide the bounds checks
    fixed (int* pSource = source)
    {
        while (i < lastBlockIndex)
        {
            result += pSource[i + 0];
            result += pSource[i + 1];
            result += pSource[i + 2];
            result += pSource[i + 3];

            i += 4;
        }

        while (i < source.Length)
        {
            result += pSource[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

А за счет чего достигается эта быстрота? Ок, я согласен, что отключение проверки границ массива увеличивает производительность. Однако, вносит ли какой-то импакт то, что на 1 итерации цикла за раз выполняется несколько суммирований?

Да, скорее всего на низком уровне уменьшилось, кол-во джампов, но разве процессор сам не способен разрулить это с помощью предсказаний и спекулятивного выполнения?

Comment: Даже при использовании предсказаний и спекулятивного выполнения проверку все равно придется реально выполнять при каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: @PashaPash с проверкой я согласен. У меня подозрение на тело цикла, то что выполнение за раз 4 сложений ничего не дает.

Comment: возьмите benchmark.net и померяйте :). про сам Loop unrolling в википедии настолько подробно расписано, что любой ответ будет просто копипастой оттуда.

Comment: в ~4 раза меньше проверок на условие остановки

Comment: Ускорение может быть за счёт меньшего числа обращений к памяти. Читается она блоками, а в каждом блоке вы используете по факту всего одно значение. Не знаю как с CPU, а на GPU такие вещи сказываются очень сильно.

Answer (score 2):

В статье прямо перед листингом написано:

> Большинство современных процессоров могут выполнять четыре операции
>   сложения за один такт (при оптимальных условиях), в следствии чего,
>   при правильной "раскладке" кода, вы можете, иногда, улучшить
>   производительность, даже в однопоточной реализации.

Ядра в современных процессорах содержат несколько ALU. Начиная с Haswell ядра интеловских процессоров содержат по [четыре арифметических вычислителя и четыре адресных блока](https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/). Поэтому каждое ядро может выполнять четыре арифметических микрооперации одновременно. И четыре операции доступа к памяти.

```
            result += pSource[i + 0];
            result += pSource[i + 1];
            result += pSource[i + 2];
            result += pSource[i + 3];
```

Здесь у вас четыре косвенных адресации, которые загружают четыре адресных блока, и четыре сложения с аккумулятором, которые загружают четыре арифметических блока. Поэтому ALU в процессоре оказывается максимально загруженным.

Помимо этого в развёрнутом цикле в четыре раза меньше сравнений, то есть в 4 раза меньше *лишних инструкций* в ALU.

Answer (score 1):

Идея простая вы уменьшаете проверки.

1. в каждой итерации цикла. Выполнение 4-х сложений за итерацию
2. Если посмотреть [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/unsafe-code#pointer-element-access) то можно прочесть следующее.

The pointer element access operator does not check for out-of-bounds errors and the behavior when accessing an out-of-bounds element is undefined

Смысл в том что когда вы получаете доступ к элементу массива через указатель то проверки выхода за границы а также действие при выходе за границы не определено. Да и сам переход P[E] приблизительно равен *(P + E).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5yY4IOw-MI конфа dotnext, доходчиво объясняют с примерами -)

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/872657)